# Iterating API parameter in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I'm trying to use this API to fetch data directly in my google spreadsheet, I'm using Google AppScript.

Below is my API

```
=ImportJSON("https://rest.yyy.com/v2/matches?date=2022-06-01(Date start - yyyy-mm-dd)_2022-07-02(Date end - yyyy-mm-dd)&per_page=2000&token=xxx-xxx-xxxx-xx&status=1,2,3,4 &paged=1")
```

There is a "Paged" value in the API parameter this parameter limits the output range.

How can I iterate the "paged" parameter so that I don't have to change it manually? So that I could get all the data at once?

I'm doing this using Google App Script.

Comment: Can you share the full code you have on Apps Script? Also, if your API call returns the page, you can get that number, add +1 to it and make another call with it.

Comment: (if your API call returns the page, you can get that number, add +1 to it and make another call with it) How can i do this ??

Comment: You can use `Logger.log()` to see the structure that the API returns and then use a for loop to get the information you need. Can you share your full code on Apps Script?